# How do I remove something that is no longer in the program, that I dragged from the View Controller to a function?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I have dragged an element onto my code. How do I undo that? Here's an image:

[image]

The Green Slider is no longer on my storyboard and yet it appears in the round tab!

Here again:

[image]

Is there a way to get rid of "Main.storyboard – Green Slider"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the pop up, it will take you to storyboard. Remove its reference from there if it exists. I have attached an image for your help:

[image]

If reference doesn't exist then do **4 steps**

1. Close your project and close Xcode
2. Open `/Users/XXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and delete
   your cache of project
3. Open `/Users/ХХХХХ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex`
   and delete
   all cache from this directory
4. Open your project again and click Product > Build

**If still exist do**

Just change one letter from name. This will cause it to break relationship to storyboard and link it again to new storyboard.

Comment: It doesn't work when the pop-up shows an item that doesn't exist.

Comment: That doesn't work. There is still a filled dot that displays an item that doesn't exist. See the new graphic in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a clean build by running command+shift+k

Another example would be to go in front of the IBOutlet and and move it to the previous line or the next line.

Comment: That doesn't work. There is still a filled dot that displays an item that doesn't exist. See the new graphic in my post.